# Setting DateTime variable as NULL in CASE expression

Tags: sql, case, sql-null

I have two DateTime columns `Date1` and `Date2`. If `Date1` is populated, `Date2` carries the same value, otherwise `Date2` carries its own unique value.

What I am trying to do is, if `Date1<>NULL`, `Date2=NULL`.
I am using a `CASE` statement within a `SELECT` Statement that fetches other values as well. But its not solving my issue.

```
CASE    
WHEN (DATE1<>NULL AND DATE2<>NULL)
THEN DATE2=NULL
ELSE DATE2
END
```

Help appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Hint:  `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Are you trying to *change* the value of Date2?

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use IS NULL / IS NOT NULL for comparison

and in case when  don't use  assignment as  DATE2 = NULL  .. use just NULL

```
CASE WHEN (DATE1 IS NOT NULL AND DATE2 IS NOT NULL) THEN  NULL ELSE DATE2 END
```

Comment: Based on the information in the question, I don't think this needs `date2 is not null`.  I believe it can just be `case when DATE1 is not null then null else DATE2 end as DATE2`

Answer (score 2):

Use `COALESCE` function, it returns the first not-null argument which is what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT COALESCE(DATE1, DATE2) AS DATE2
```